# How can I get IIS to prevent script execution in a file upload directory?

Tags: iis, iis-8.5

My application allows users to upload files to a directory which is served from the web application. In most use-cases we use S3 but we also have a mode for customers who want to use their own hosting in which we just write the files straight to the hard disk.

We have a whitelist of allowed file types and we prevent files like .asp, .aspx, .asa, etc being accepted by the application. However I am concerned that if a way was found around this, an attacker could upload an .aspx file and take control of the web server process.

While investigating this I discovered that our MVC application reports an exception when attempting to access a path that doesn't exist within this directory. I am secondarily concerned that we are perhaps going to see less than optimal performance as a result of this; surely it is faster to not evaluate a path using MVC and just use a static content handler?

I think perhaps I am asking two questions that have the same answer:

- How can I prevent a .gif file from being passed through my ASP.NET MVC application before returning a 404?
- How can I prevent all content in a directory from being executable by ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have discovered that the way to do this is to clear all handlers and then re-add the static content handler. I added a web.config file to my uploads directory with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <clear />
            <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It is consequently not possible to execute .ASPX files in this directory.